# App Engine: Loading data into memory of automatically scaled instances

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, go, google-cloud-datastore

**Each instance of my application module** [default] **needs to load data from the datastore into local memory** (for performance/cost reasons), where it will be read-only.

**A separate module updates the data in the datastore** [updater], and the data needs to be refreshed (entirely) in each default instance every several minutes (preferably when the data is updated by the updater module).

Loading the data into instance memory takes more time than is reasonable for a single user request.

I would have used a thread (goroutine) with a background context to reload the data in each [default] instance, but background context is not supported in automatically scaled modules.

**How should I update each [default] instance's memory when the data is updated by the updater module?**

I am using the go runtime environment.

Comment: look into using memcached

Comment: I feel your approach is wrong for appengine. How do you propose to cause a refresh of the data every few minutes.  You would have to direct a request to the specific instance that hits a handler to call refresh.  And if it's expensive during warmup request it will be no more efficient later.  As the previous comment suggests use memcache.  You can then use the local instance memory as an additional caching layer, but this cache is harder to expire.  I would keep it as a request level cache, i.e if you fetch the same entities from memcache more than once in a request, then cache it locally